# Airline Seat information - SOAP API

Tags: soap, sabre

What type Airline seat information is available from the itinerary soap api? The TravelItineraryReadRQ sample provide the seat details for cruise but not from flight segment.

Answer (score 0):

If looking to get specific Seat Map information for Flights, you are best consuming the Enhanced Seat Map API -

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/seat_map

Comment: We are looking for the assigned seat for an existing booking.

Comment: The actual service does provide that information, see example below for more full response http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/pnrservices/TravelItineraryReadRS_3.6.0_Design.xml

Comment: jmacagno is correct. See ReservationItems/Item RPH="9"/Seats in the provided sample, for an example of how seats are reflected in TravelItineraryReadRQ response